# Relationship between equivalent norms and ball subsets?

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider unit balls under norms $\|\cdot\|_i$ and $\|\cdot\|_j$:

$$
B(0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb R|\,\,\,\|x\|_i<1 \}
$$

$$
\hat B(0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb R|\,\,\,\|x\|_j<1 \}
$$

Consider now the equivalence relation between norms $\|\cdot\|_i$ and $\|\cdot\|_j$:

$$
m_l\|\cdot\|_i\le\|\cdot\|_j\le m_u\|\cdot\|_i \tag{1}
$$

I have managed to intuitively understand (using simpler examples) that this implies the following geometric property:

$$
\hat B(0,1\cdot m_l)\subseteq B(0,1)\subseteq\hat B(0,1\cdot m_u) \tag{2}
$$

My problem is that I am unable to get to this final result mathematically, i.e. by manipulating symbols instead of drawing on paper. Show me please how to use (1) in order to obtain (2). Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure the inclusions in your (2) go the right way?

Comment: So you know how to get from "equivalent norms" of definition to statement (1)? Is that correct? And then you'd like to get from (1) to (2)?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes that is correct. Henning, yes I'm pretty sure they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The punchline is that, for the left containment, you need to divide by $m_l$. I've changed the notation I'm using below for simplicity, but the argument remains the same.

Suppose $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ are norms on a vector space $V$ and that there exist $m,M > 0$ such that $m\|x\| \leq \|x\|_1 \leq M\|x\|$ for all $x \in V$. For each $r > 0$ let $B(0,r)$ and $B_1(0,r)$ denote the balls of radius $r$ centered at $0$ in $V$ under the norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$, respectively.

Suppose $x \in B(0,1)$. Then $\|x\| \leq 1$, and so $\|x\|_1 \leq M\|x\| \leq M$. Therefore $x \in B_1(0,M)$, which shows that $B(0,1) \subseteq B_1(0,M)$.

Similarly, if $y \in B_1(0,m)$ then manipulating the given inequalities shows that $\|y\| \leq (1/m)\|y\|_1 \leq 1$, and so $y \in B(0,1)$. Thus $B_1(0,m) \subseteq B(0,1) \subseteq B_1(0,M)$.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @space_voyager Sure thing! `:)`

Comment: @Dan how do you know that $||x||_1\leq M$?

Comment: @johnny09: Substitution: I know that $\|x\|_1 \leq M\|x\|$ for all $x \in V$ by our hypothesis relating $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$. We've assumed $x \in B(0,1)$, so $\|x\| \leq 1$ and therefore $M\|x\| \leq M$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\|\cdot\|_j \le \alpha \|\cdot\|_i$.  Then $$x \in B(0,1) \implies \|x\|_i < 1 \implies \|x\|_j < \alpha \implies x \in \hat B(0,\alpha).$$ That is, $B(0,1) \subset \hat B(0,\alpha)$.

You can use similar reasoning for the other inclusion.

Comment: Thanks, but what did I misstate?

Comment: I don't know. I think I misread what you stated in (1).